# Show that $\lVert A \rVert_T := \lVert T^{-1} A T \rVert$ is a subordinate (induced) norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I saw the following claim in many places without proof: Given an induced norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$,

$$ \lVert A \rVert_T := \lVert T^{-1} A T \rVert $$

is also an induced norm. All of the texts I saw skip the proof claiming it is easy. However, I couldn't prove it myself. It is pretty easy to show that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_T$ is a submultiplicative matrix norm, but how can I show that it is also an induced norm?

Comment: With induced norm, you mean that for $A:X \rightarrow X$, there is a norm $|\cdot|$ on $X$ such that $\|\cdot \|_T = \max_{x\in X |x|=1}|Ax|$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Also, I will drop the $i$ subscript as it might be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're looking for a vector norm $|\cdot|_T$ on $X$ such that $$\|A\|_T = \max_{x \in X} \frac{|Ax|_T}{|x|_T} \left(= \max_{x \in X, |x|_T = 1} |Ax|_T\right),$$

i.e. $\|\cdot\|_T$ is induced by $|\cdot|_T$.

Let $|x|_T = |T^{-1}x|$. (Is this a norm?)

Then we have:

$$\max_{x\in X}  \frac{|Ax|_T}{|x|_T} =\max_{y\in X}  \frac{|ATy|_T}{|Ty|_T} =\max_{y\in X}  \frac{|T^{-1}ATy|}{|T^{-1}Ty|}  \\= \max_{y\in X}  \frac{|T^{-1}ATy|}{|y|} =\max_{y\in X, |y| = 1}  |T^{-1}ATy|= \|T^{-1}AT\|,$$

where we have substituted $y = T^{-1}x$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is pretty easy after all :)